# PostgreSQL function giving all rows but not in key value pair format?

Tags: postgresql, laravel

I have table called `users` in PostgreSQL.I want to get all users in table from my Laravel application.

I can get from table directly as:

```
$testData = DB::table('users')->get();
```

output is:

```
 [{"id":1,"name":"Chris Sevilleja","username":"sevilayha","email":"chris@scotch.io","password":"$2y$08$i\/ATa68ierqRL47ZxHX4EesJGEcdtKPckZs8GDGpYS.IR4aaQn.\/q","created_at":"2016-09-07 09:32:41","updated_at":"2016-09-07 09:32:41"},{"id":2,"name":"Bemagoni chandrashekar","username":"chandrashekar","email":"chandrashekar@zessta.com","password":"$2y$08$QG9JsAerYp3UYpXNNyImhuz\/6hiWv8XpURpJX1uJ.hAm8l1RG2JrC","created_at":"2016-09-07 09:32:41","updated_at":"2016-09-07 09:32:41"},{"id":3,"name":"dwefr","username":"ewre","email":"ewrt@egyfrhgt.com","password":"$2y$08$s2XBZvoAvpEqjjhbx8QPw.eSe5TIuJC25XbaFkTskzAKAGi99QWga","created_at":"2016-09-07 09:34:27","updated_at":"2016-09-07 09:34:27"},{"id":4,"name":"r3t54y6u677i","username":"retrytyu","email":"etyru@dddj.com","password":"$2y$08$Xb0Xm4KwdSwcBSHX0F6ETOWU60X.NO5D7\/uwVv\/xUAXTUS8LSPCLu","created_at":"2016-09-07 09:46:26","updated_at":"2016-09-07 09:46:26"},{"id":5,"name":"r3t45y6u","username":"ertrh","email":"435t4y65@sss.com","password":"$2y$08$36DLu49nZ2YOWtU.c625meiyi3\/fmsHxiTuxIU9z9UcyrbIpFSKKW","created_at":"2016-09-07 10:02:05","updated_at":"2016-09-07 10:02:05"},{"id":6,"name":"ewrtryuyj","username":"ryt","email":"wrewtey@sssks.com","password":"$2y$08$GULHtX3GGXPGgm8gA9yDbeawZlQ5QwD2TX7nrCvEU4j7jrSgPWAQO","created_at":"2016-09-07 10:04:17","updated_at":"2016-09-07 10:04:17"},{"id":7,"name":"chandu","username":"chandu","email":"ch1235hdhd@dhdjd.com","password":"$2y$08$gpAhcl\/Sg.lGvb.zk.I\/m.PfcttGI6OPFMsMxQVm15dYOtQDvIWSG","created_at":"2016-09-07 10:06:18","updated_at":"2016-09-07 10:06:18"},{"id":8,"name":"dewfergt","username":"erwrgf","email":"fgf@dgrf.com","password":"$2y$08$ikYAXV1prZsEj2MPxXM4S.Tqn160Jv25cFOQLghK8ptFiSBaIFGZO","created_at":"2016-09-07 10:07:20","updated_at":"2016-09-07 10:07:20"},{"id":9,"name":"rteryt","username":"wrwter","email":"wretr@gjjd.com","password":"$2y$08$pkOUBl1NlNdBShNWiklya.0zlPzPrEH2edCfvdCiHLnj80GY1sdtm","created_at":"2016-09-08 07:11:46","updated_at":"2016-09-08 07:11:46"},{"id":10,"name":"Raghu","username":"raghu","email":"raghu@gdgdjd.com","password":"$2y$08$m9wke.vvTTZytYw91I4\/q.qxKoCobLOW7dbCvs66xFyJyy2R9phni","created_at":"2016-09-10 10:06:40","updated_at":"2016-09-10 10:06:40"},{"id":11,"name":"wewert","username":"ewretr","email":"ewrtey@vsss.com","password":"$2y$08$IXD0eXYTPPGE1MfALonEFey0lr\/KBMZ0.3AIO3sWVgu7IZdWhXwTG","created_at":"2016-09-12 07:48:58","updated_at":"2016-09-12 07:48:58"}]
```

Through PostgreSQL function calling:

my PostgreSQL function:

```
-- Function: public."RegiterUsers2"()

-- DROP FUNCTION public."RegiterUsers2"();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."RegiterUsers2"()
  RETURNS SETOF users AS
'select * from users'
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION public."RegiterUsers2"()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Laravel code:

```
$allUserData=DB::select('SELECT public."RegiterUsers2"()')
```

output:

```
[{"RegiterUsers2":"(1,\"Chris Sevilleja\",sevilayha,chris@scotch.io,$2y$08$i\/ATa68ierqRL47ZxHX4EesJGEcdtKPckZs8GDGpYS.IR4aaQn.\/q,\"2016-09-07 09:32:41\",\"2016-09-07 09:32:41\")"},{"RegiterUsers2":"(2,\"Bemagoni chandrashekar\",chandrashekar,chandrashekar@zessta.com,$2y$08$QG9JsAerYp3UYpXNNyImhuz\/6hiWv8XpURpJX1uJ.hAm8l1RG2JrC,\"2016-09-07 09:32:41\",\"2016-09-07 09:32:41\")"},{"RegiterUsers2":"(3,dwefr,ewre,ewrt@egyfrhgt.com,$2y$08$s2XBZvoAvpEqjjhbx8QPw.eSe5TIuJC25XbaFkTskzAKAGi99QWga,\"2016-09-07 09:34:27\",\"2016-09-07 09:34:27\")"},{"RegiterUsers2":"(4,r3t54y6u677i,retrytyu,etyru@dddj.com,$2y$08$Xb0Xm4KwdSwcBSHX0F6ETOWU60X.NO5D7\/uwVv\/xUAXTUS8LSPCLu,\"2016-09-07 09:46:26\",\"2016-09-07 09:46:26\")"},{"RegiterUsers2":"(5,r3t45y6u,ertrh,435t4y65@sss.com,$2y$08$36DLu49nZ2YOWtU.c625meiyi3\/fmsHxiTuxIU9z9UcyrbIpFSKKW,\"2016-09-07 10:02:05\",\"2016-09-07 10:02:05\")"},{"RegiterUsers2":"(6,ewrtryuyj,ryt,wrewtey@sssks.com,$2y$08$GULHtX3GGXPGgm8gA9yDbeawZlQ5QwD2TX7nrCvEU4j7jrSgPWAQO,\"2016-09-07 10:04:17\",\"2016-09-07 10:04:17\")"},{"RegiterUsers2":"(7,chandu,chandu,ch1235hdhd@dhdjd.com,$2y$08$gpAhcl\/Sg.lGvb.zk.I\/m.PfcttGI6OPFMsMxQVm15dYOtQDvIWSG,\"2016-09-07 10:06:18\",\"2016-09-07 10:06:18\")"},{"RegiterUsers2":"(8,dewfergt,erwrgf,fgf@dgrf.com,$2y$08$ikYAXV1prZsEj2MPxXM4S.Tqn160Jv25cFOQLghK8ptFiSBaIFGZO,\"2016-09-07 10:07:20\",\"2016-09-07 10:07:20\")"},{"RegiterUsers2":"(9,rteryt,wrwter,wretr@gjjd.com,$2y$08$pkOUBl1NlNdBShNWiklya.0zlPzPrEH2edCfvdCiHLnj80GY1sdtm,\"2016-09-08 07:11:46\",\"2016-09-08 07:11:46\")"},{"RegiterUsers2":"(10,Raghu,raghu,raghu@gdgdjd.com,$2y$08$m9wke.vvTTZytYw91I4\/q.qxKoCobLOW7dbCvs66xFyJyy2R9phni,\"2016-09-10 10:06:40\",\"2016-09-10 10:06:40\")"},{"RegiterUsers2":"(11,wewert,ewretr,ewrtey@vsss.com,$2y$08$IXD0eXYTPPGE1MfALonEFey0lr\/KBMZ0.3AIO3sWVgu7IZdWhXwTG,\"2016-09-12 07:48:58\",\"2016-09-12 07:48:58\")"}]
```

I need like this

```
    {"id":1,
"name":"Chris Sevilleja",
"username":"sevilayha",
"email":"chris@scotch.io",
"password":"$2y$08$i\/ATa68ierqRL47ZxHX4EesJGEcdtKPckZs8GDGpYS.IR4aaQn",
"created_at":"2016-09-07 09:32:41",
"updated_at":"2016-09-07 09:32:41"},
```

so what is wrong with postgres function and how can I get like above one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a function returning many columns and you want each one, you must call in the form of:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM function(...)
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM function(...)
```

So in your case you simple want:

```
$allUserData=DB::select('SELECT * FROM public."RegiterUsers2"()')
```

Comment: @ChandrashekarBemagoni you an accept the answer then... ;)

Comment: is there any other way to call Postgres function from Laravel?

Comment: Not sure @ChandrashekarBemagoni, I'm no Laravel expert